# AngularJS Autocomplete IE9 Issue

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am new to Angular JS and I am doing form validation for login page using Angular Js. If I enter username and password, it is working fine But if I choose remember credentials in browser and choose autocomplete options next time, my Submit button is not enabled. I am facing this issue only in IE9. for rest of the browsers its working fine. Any suggestions for this. My login.html looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="username" 
       class="login" 
       value="" 
       name="userId" 
       type="text" 
       required/>

<input ng-model="password" 
       class="login" 
       value="" 
       name="password" 
       type="password" 
       required/>

<button class="primaryButton" 
       type="submit" 
       ng-click="loginUser()" 
       ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid"/>
```

Also, as per one blog, I tried adding directive for this. By adding directive, If I choose autocomplete options and just mouse click somewhere, submit button is enabled. But I don't want to click after choosing autocomplete option.
My directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('sampleModule').directive('autofill', function autofill(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
          return element.val();
        }, function(nv, ov) {
          if(nv !== ov) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(nv);
          }
        });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: wait! uses jquery events to monitor element changes... but I had used a simple timeout function to monitor that. I will to post my code below

Answer (score 1):

You may need to apply a timeout to your directive's logic to force it to alert IE that it needs to re-render.

```
angular.module('sampleModule').directive('autofill', ['$timeout', 
  function autofill($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
          $timeout(function () {
             return element.val();
          }, 0);
        }, function(nv, ov) {
          $timeout(function () {
            if(nv !== ov) {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(nv);
            }
          }, 0);
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: use $timeout instead,,no need to worry about digest cycle

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy at interval times, because IE9 (and chrome) doesn't emit events for user and password autocomplete.

Set respective ids for inputs, and then:

```
app.controller('yourController', function($scope, $interval) {

    $interval(function() {
        $scope.username = $('#username').val();
        $scope.password = $('#password').val();
    }, 1000);  // each 1 second
});
```

of course, you can adapt this soluction to your directive.

Comment: @pankajparkar: timeout thing is not working for me. When I apply timeout, it hangs browser as soon as I open login page. I can't proceed with login and every time I have to kill browser. Also,I try increasing its value from 0 to 1000. With that, it hangs after 1 sec of opening login page.

Comment: @joaozita: I tried adding interval approach in directive but it didn't work for me either. Its not updating username and password values.

Comment: I create a new directive to try it... I will post were... I also have the same problem in my code, and I'm trying to solve now.

Answer (score 0):

try a directive to call change from element:

```
directive('monitorAutoFill', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            $timeout(function() {
                el.trigger('change');
            }, 500);
        }
    };
});
```

and, on your inputs:

```
<input ng-model="username" 
   class="login" 
   value="" 
   name="userId" 
   type="text" 
   required
   monitor-auto-fill />

<input ng-model="password" 
   class="login" 
   value="" 
   name="password" 
   type="password" 
   required
   monitor-auto-fill />
```

Comment: This directive is working very well on Chrome. You have tried on IE9?